# Can't remove a snap app

Tags: 20.04, snap, software-uninstall

(Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I'm newish to ubuntu, having used it for a while 15 years ago)
So, I installed Okular from the software centre, didn't need it so uninstalled it pretty much straightaway. Then a few hours later I was nosing around and saw an Okular folder in a Snap folder in Home, so I permanently deleted it. Probably a bad decision, but I was feeling angry!
Then, Okular turned up in the applications list, so I tried a `snap list` in terminal and there it was. I tried a `snap remove okular` and it came up with a few reasons why it couldn't remove it. I did a `snap remove --purge okular` hoping to get rid of any remnants but after apparently removing some files it again put out an "error: cannot perform the following tasks:"

```
Disconnect okular:kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22 from kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22:kf5-5-108- 
qt-5-15-10-core22-slot (internal error: connection "okular:kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22 
kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22:kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22-slot" not found in state)
```

and at this point I have no idea what else to do. The app shows as installed but can't be opened or removed. I could just ignore it, but if anyone has any ideas I'd gratefully hear them.

Comment: Did you use sudo? `sudo snap remove okular`?

Comment: I have tried that, to no avail:

Comment: `sudo snap remove okular` = `error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Disconnect okular:network from snapd:network (internal error: connection "okular:network snapd:network" not found in state)` and `sudo snap remove --purge okular` = `error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Disconnect okular:icon-themes from gtk-common-themes:icon-themes (internal error: connection "okular:icon-themes gtk-common-themes:icon-themes" not found in state)`

Comment: @karel No that doesn't help. I seem to have deleted some files that are required to uninstall the app that I previously uninstalled... I've searched and searched but there's nothing about how to get rid of an app that can't be got rid of.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I would like to share my solution although I did not know the reason. Hope it helps.

For me, I noticed that `kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22` is installed along with Okular. So I first

```bash
sudo snap remove kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22 --purge
```

which works well. Then run

```bash
sudo snap remove okular --purge
```

but it failed. Then I rebooted my PC, and ran the above command again, it succeeded.